# Ready every count until raspy seers inure oaths noble

Tags: riddle, cipher, poetry, acrostic

*Entry into [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #38: Reusing Information 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6458/fortnightly-topic-challenge-38-reusing-information-1)*
<sub>I'm hoping this fits into this.</sub>

> Right is a just cause, or a just cause is right.
> Every day should be happy, or happiness should be found daily each.
> Deeds deserve a delicious apple, or apples are delicious after a good deed.
> Double all of your ideas, or all your ideas are worth double.
> Even puritans like these stakes, or stakes are used by these puritans, even.
> Real answers here in mazes, or by mazes will you find these answers real.
>
> By fives you shall find the first, by repetition you shall find the second. I am the programmer's friend.

Hint

> letter count is not the way to solve the second part, though counting may be required.

Hint 2:

> Not all acrostics have been found.

Hint 3:

> The second part is found by something with five and repeating something from the first part.

Hint 4:

> The second part is another acrostic found by five.

Final Hint:

> The word you're looking for is not commonly used, if that helps.

Super Ultra Final Hint:

> As David Starkey notes, the first half of each line is always five words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the answer is

> chaism

Which can be found by

> taking the first letter from the 5th word of each line of the original text.

For those (like me) unfamiliar with the word

> it appears related to [Chiastic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiastic_structure) which is a literary technique with "often symmetrical patterns"

Notes (the jottings of a madman):

> The only letters unused are `Q` and `X`
>  First letters of each line spell out `REDDER` (this is also true of the first letters of the last words of each line)
>  First half of each line is always 5 words
>  The 3rd line has a lot of words starting with `D`
>  The first line is the only one completely composed of repeated words
>  i.stack.imgur uses 5 characters, so maybe we need to end up there somehow

The repeated words are

> a (x4)
>  all (x2)
>  answers (x2)
>  are (x3)
>  be (x2)
>  by (x2)
>  cause (x2)
>  delicious (x2)
>  double (x2)
>  even (x2)
>  ideas (x2)
>  is (x2)
>  just (x2)
>  mazes (x2)
>  or (x6)
>  puritans (x2)
>  real (x2)
>  right (x2)
>  should (x2)
>  stakes (x2)
>  these (x3)
>  your (x2)

meaning single-use words are

> after
>  apple
>  apples
>  daily
>  day
>  deed
>  deeds
>  deserve
>  each
>  every
>  find
>  found
>  good
>  happiness
>  happy
>  here
>  in
>  like
>  of
>  used
>  will
>  worth
>  you

Which means the text using only repeated words is

> Right is a just cause or a just cause is right
>  should be or should be
>  a delicious or are delicious a
>  Double all your ideas or all your ideas are double
>  Even puritans these stakes or stakes are by these puritans even
>  Real answers mazes or by mazes these answers real

And the text using only unique words is

> Every day happy, happiness found daily each.
>  Deeds deserve apple, apples after good deed.
>  of worth
>  like used
>  here in will you find.

Unless we assume "similar" words count for repeating (like apple/apples), which would then give us a unique message of:

> Every found each.
>  deserve after good.
>  of worth
>  like used
>  here in will you find.

If we take every 5th word, we get

> after used find ([auf](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/auf))

which is maybe something?  Following that in the original gives the word `by`.

Alternatively

> The only line with 5 words is "here in will you find"

The repeated version with "similar" words counting is:

> Right is a just cause, or a just cause is right
>  day should be happy, or happiness should be daily
>  Deeds a delicious apple, or apples are delicious a deed
>  Double all your ideas or all your ideas are double
>  Even puritans these stakes or stakes are by these puritans even
>  Real answers mazes or by mazes these answers real

Taking every 5th word gives

> cause is happy daily or deed or double or puritans or real (cihdododopor)

Comment: I'd argue the similar words, i.e. happy and happiness are repeats too. Or else, that's what I meant by it.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I had debated on whether they should be counted, but decided to take a literal approach, since it would be easier to remove those and not worry about which version to use in the list.  I updated with some more random ideas, but I'm still at a loss for where to go next.  Checking acrostics in every way I could think of (5th letter of each line, first letter of every 5th word, etc.) doesn't seems to lead to anything.  I'll try coming back to this at some later point, which might help give new perspective.

Comment: Wait, one of those ways would most certainly give you something (cough, cough, acrostic, the fifth word of every line). Like I mentioned, it may not be a word you're familiar with.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I believe I found it.

Comment: Sorry, you got it. Nice job!

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

I have a guess as to what the answer is - I just have no idea how to get to it!
Or maybe it's just a hint to the process of finding the answer

But while I'm working that out, I'm going to go with

> Recursion

because

> It's in the title (acrostic), the last line indicates using a recursive process to find the answer, and recursion can be a programmer's friend.

By fives you shall find the first...

> It's the five letter words in the title that yield RECURSION

So
... by repetition you shall find the second

> Presumably something to do with the words which are repeated. Or maybe the ones which aren't

Comment: This is the first part. Now use that to find the second part! :)

Comment: Heh heh, you're thinking right on some things.